# How can i upload an image in a form for a product catalog?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload an product image but, in the form, I treceive this error list:

> The prixlivre field is required.
>
> The imagelivre must be an image.
>
> The imagelivre must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg.

Just above, here is the three errors list that I got.

My blade.php code:

```
@extends('layouts.appadmin')

@section('title')
    Ajouter un livre
@endsection

@section('contenu')


    <div class="row grid-margin">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Ajouter un livre</h4>

                  @if (Session::has('status'))
                  <div class="alert alert-success">
                      {{Session::get('status')}}
                  </div>
                  @endif
                  @if ($errors->any())
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          <ul>
                              @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                              @endforeach
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                  @endif

                  <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('livres.sauverlivre') }}">
                    @csrf
                  <fieldset>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="cemail">Nom du livre</label>
                      <input id="cemail" class="form-control" type="text" name="nomLivre" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cemail">Prix du livre</label>
                        <input id="cemail" class="form-control" type="number" name="prixLivre" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cemail">Image du livre</label>
                        <input type="file" name="imageLivre" class="form-control" id="cemail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cemail">Catégorie du livre</label>
                        <select name="categorie_id" id="cemail" class="form-control">
                            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">VEUILLEZ SELECTIONNER</option>

                            @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
                                <option value="{{ $categorie->id }}">{{ $categorie->category_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach

                        </select>
                      </div>

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Ajouter">

                  </fieldset>

                  </form>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


@endsection

@section('scripts')
    {{--<script src="Administrateur/js/form-validation.js"></script>
    <script src="Administrateur/js/bt-maxLength.js"></script>--}}
@endsection
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categorie;
use App\Models\Livre;


class LivreController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function ajouterlivre(){
        $categories = Categorie::all();
        return view('admin.ajouterlivre', [
            'categories'=>$categories,
        ]);
    }

    public function sauverlivre(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'nomLivre' => 'required|unique:livres',
            'PrixLivre' => 'required',
            'imageLivre' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'categorie_id' => 'required',
        ]);
  
        $input = $request->all();
  
        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'image/';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }
    
        Livre::create($input);

 return redirect('/ajouterlivre')->with('status', 'Un livre a été ajouté avec succès');
 
}
```

How can I solve that? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` element.

Comment: in which part of the code please? Enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: I didn't think that sentence was unclear, but here we are... You only have one have `<form>` element: `<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('livres.sauverlivre') }}">`, you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`: `<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('livres.sauverlivre') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Hello, I did it but that still gives errors, and this time, it is just one error and that's about price. I receive this: The prix livre field is required.

Comment: It is that:  The prix livre field is required.                                                                                                 Just that this time. How can I do to solve it ?

Comment: `name="prixLivre"` vs `'PrixLivre' => 'required',` - Not sure if case-sensitivity matters, but those are currently not the same.

Comment: However, I wrote the codes correctly I think                                                                                        Here is my migration file: 
        Schema::create('livres', function (Blueprint $table) {$table->increments('id');$table->string('nomLivre')->unique(); $table->integer('prixLivre'); $table->string('imageLivre'); $table->integer('statusLivre'); $table->integer('categorie_id')->unsigned(); $table->foreign('categorie_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade'); $table->timestamps(); });

Comment: It is prixLivre I have chosen

Comment: Hello that work now but i have one other anything, not about price, this time, it's about the table livre in the migration file that I sent earlier. The error is : **Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'statusLivre' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `livres` (`nomLivre`, `prixLivre`, `categorie_id`, `imageLivre`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ERTFD, 10000, 1, C:\xampp\tmp\php1ED0.tmp, 2023-02-10 19:32:23, 2023-02-10 19:32:23))**

Comment: Please start reading and searching for these errors; you're not the first person to encounter them, and there are existing questions and answers here (and other places) that show how to handle these. That error is self-explanatory; you're trying to save a `livres` row, but you're not passing a `statusLivre` value, and it doesn't have a default value in the database, or allow `null`. **You have to fix that** by either passing a value or adjusting your migration to include a default value, or allow `null`.

Comment: I don't want to use the statusLivre in the form of adding a product, I just want to use it in admin in order to activate or deactivate a product using bollean values ​​and this to display afterwards in a datatable if a product is enabled or not. But for the add form I don't want to use it in it. Now it sends me this error to tell me that 'statusLivre' doesn't have a default value

Comment: I know, but once again, **you need to handle this**. Right now, that column **NEEDS** a value, since you've defined it as `$table->integer('statusLivre');`. If you're not going to pass a value via the Form, then you need to change that to either allow `null`, or have a default value, like `$table->integer('statusLivre')->nullable();`, or `$table->integer('statusLivre')->default(...);` (replacing `...` with an actual value). Or, pass a value in your Form. You need to figure out what you want to do and implement it; I can't make that decision for you 